# How to add a delete button on each row of jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, datatables

I am trying to use a jquery datatables using ajax sourced data in my application.

My table html would be

```
<table id="dynaFormVersionTable" class="table table-striped table-hover dt-responsive" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Form Id</th>
                <th>Form Title</th>
                <th>Version</th> 
                <th>Created Date</th>   
                <th>Modified Date</th>
                <th>Created By</th>
                <th>Select</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
     </table>
```

and I am making the following call using ajax to load the datatable with the required data which is in the form of json

```
$('#dynaFormVersionTable').dataTable({

        "ajax": {
                "url": "${rc.getContextPath()}/module/dynamic-forms/form-versions",
                type: "GET",
                data: {
                webcontentid: ${webcontentid},
                },
                "dataSrc":  "",
                },

        "columns":[
        {"data": "webContentDefinitionId"},
        {"data": "webContentTitle"},
        {"data": "formVersion"},
        {"data": "createdTime",
        "render": function (data) {
        var date = new Date(data);
        var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        return  date.getDate() + "/" + (month.length > 1 ? month : "0" + month) + "/"  + date.getFullYear();
        }
        },
        {"data": "updatedTime",
        "render": function (data) {
        var date = new Date(data);
        var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        return  date.getDate() + "/" + (month.length > 1 ? month : "0" + month) + "/"  + date.getFullYear();
        }
        },
        {"data": "userCreated"},
        {data: null ,
        "sClass" : "center",
        "sDefaultContent" : '<a href = "" class ="editor_edit">Select</a> '
        },
        ],

     });
```

The json data contains the following details:

```
[
{  
      "dfWebContentDefinitionId":18,
      "webContentDefinitionId":800,
      "webContentTitle":"DFTest6-edt1",
      "webContentDesc":"DFTest6",
      "webContentKwd":"DFTest6",
      "webContentViewUrl":null,
      "webContentEditUrl":null,
      "webContentMediaUrl":"/files/doc-lib/2015/02/15/11/58/48/246/head/test.jpg",
      "webContentType":"content",
      "officeId":null,
      "createdTime":1426172671199,
      "updatedTime":1426172671199,
      "userCreated":"adm",
      "userModified":"adm",
      "webContentStatus":null,
      "webLinkType":null,
      "webContentId":0,
      "formVersion":3
   }
]
```

What I am trying is to display a button named 'Select' on each row an clicking on which the row has to be selected. But I am unable to set a button.

Comment: i'm a little confused: what do you want to do? from title: _add a delete button_, from post: _select row_. what you mean _select_?

Answer (score 2):

it is as simple as returning the html from the server in the json, for example:

define your column as any other column(`I am omitting a lot of code`)

```
"columns" : [
    //.....omitted code
   //your button column
   {data: "deleteButton", "sClass" : "center"}
]
```

later, in your json data

```
[
{  
      //..omitted code
      "webContentId":0,
      "formVersion":3
      "deleteButton": "<a href=\"\" class=\"editor_edit\">Select</a>"
   }
]
```

also, you need to check the documentation of [Server-side processing](http://datatables.net/manual/server-side) because the expected JSON data to be returned , needs some parameters to work properly.

you should also take a look to the [Ajax sourced data](http://datatables.net/examples/ajax/) examples. Use a debug tool like Firebug to see the ajax request.

Now, if you are using DataTables >=1.10 you need to read the [columns.data reference](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) because they change `sDefaultContent` for `defaultContent`. Read the doc [here](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.defaultContent)